# Sinusbot in aws amazon EC2 web interface not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

i successfully install sinusbot in my aws EC2 free tier with the help of 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hvf2PEGVA8k
some code i put latest from https://github.com/flyth/ts3soundbot/wiki/Installation---Debian-&-Ubuntu 
its running now perfectly i thought but web interface not opening
its refuse connection than i did change from ec2 managment console and add custom tcp and udp 8087 for anywhere but it still not working help me
i am using ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I Think the Web Interface has no permission to enter the bot try to open the port you are using. You probably have given yourself just ssh. But this is not enough for the Webinterface. I hope my English is good enough I'm still a german Children .